# D3 mouse release event

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events, dom-events

I am looking for release event on D3.

Actually, my examples has:

```
.on("mouseover", function(data){...} )
.on("mousemove", function(data){...} )
.on("mouseout", function(data){...} )
```

which works perfect, but if I try to do something like:

```
.on("release", function(data){...} )
```

it doesn't works.

Any idea?

Comment: Done!

The attribute is:

.on("mouseup", function(data){alert(1);} );
Hope to help others :D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Done!

The attribute is:

```
.on("mouseup", function(data){alert(1);} );
```

The problem also was related where I

Comment: When you answer your own question, it's good practice to close it by checking the check mark next to your answer - you won't get any reputation from this, but it will mark the question as closed and highlight the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! I try, but need to wait 1 day to do it (22 hs now). :D

Answer (score 0):

For reference -- D3 only supports [native DOM events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events).